# get the line number that a user has clicked in a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, xaml, textblock

Is it possible to get the line number of a line of text within a textblock when a user clicks?
Lets say a User clicks the 3rd line in a Text block, can I capture that information?

```
<TextBlock x:Name="WorkspaceVersion" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="879,45,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="703" Width="526" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="14">
        <TextBlock.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkColorKey}}"/>
        </TextBlock.Background>

  // then the handler here
  WorkspaceVersion.MouseLeftButtonDown += new   MouseButtonEventHandler(WorkSpaceVersion_MouseLeftButtonDown);

  // handler
  private void WorkSpaceVersion_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // can I caputer the line number of a click?
    }
```

I am open to using a different contorl for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved this by getting the X,Y coords of the click within the TextBlock Area and the dividing Y by line height.

```
private void WorkSpaceVersion_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   Point position = e.GetPosition(WorkspaceVersion);
   var i = Math.Round(position.Y/15); // line height brah
}
```

Comment: That is what I was going to answer :)

Comment: You can cast e.Source to a TextBlock and get the line height there.  No need to hard-code the line-height.